# Node js with express return connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Tags: node.js, laravel, redis, socket.io

I have a socket running in nodejs and using this socket in html page this is working fine and some times I'm receiving the error on developer console as like 
**failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response**. In this time my update not getting reflect on the user screen. Actually whenever the changes updated in admin screen I written the login in laravel to store this values into the redis and I have used the laravel event broadcast and in node js socket.io read the redis value change and push the values into the user screens.
I have code in laravel as like,
Laravel Controller,

```
public function updatecommoditygroup(Request $request)
    {
        $request_data = array();
        parse_str($request, $request_data);
        app('redis')->set("ssahaitrdcommoditydata", json_encode($request_data['commodity']));
        event(new SSAHAITRDCommodityUpdates($request_data['commodity']));
    }
```

In this above controller when the api call receives just store the values into this redis key and broadcast the event.
In my event class,

```
public $updatedata;

    public function __construct($updatedata)
    {
        $this->updatedata = $updatedata;
    }
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['ssahaitrdupdatecommodity'];
    }
```

Finally I have written my socket.io file as like below,

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis({ port: 6379 } );
redis.subscribe('ssahaitrdupdatecommodity', function(err, count) {
});
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('A client connected');
});

redis.on('pmessage', function(subscribed, channel, data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + data.event, data.data);
});
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
http.listen(3001, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3001');
});
```

When I have update the data from admin I'm passing to laravel controller, and controller will store the received data into redis database and pass to event broadcast.And event broadcast pass the values to socket server and socket server push the data whenever the redis key get change to client page.
In client page I have written the code as like below,

```
<script src="../assets/js/socket.io.js"></script>
var socket = io('http://ip:3001/');
socket.on("novnathupdatecommodity:App\\Events\\NOVNATHCommodityUpdates", function(data){
//received data processing in client
});
```

Everything working fine in most of the time and some times issue facing like

```
**VM35846 socket.io.js:7 WebSocket connection to 'ws://host:3001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=p8EsriJGGCemaon3ASuh' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response**
```

By this issue user page not getting update with new data. Could you please anyone help me to solve this issue and give the best solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your socket connection timeout.

```
new io({
  path:,
  serveClient:,
  orgins:,
  pingTimeout:,
  pingInterval: 
});
```

The above is the socket configuration. If you are not configuring socket sometime it behaves strangely. I do not know the core reason, but i too have faced similar issues that implementing the socket configuration solved it.

[Socket.io Server](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/9c1e73c752aec63f48b511330a506d037783d897/docs/API.md)

Similar configuration should be done on the client side. There is an option of timeout in client side

[Socket.io Client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/docs/API.md)

For example.

Say this is your front-end code
You connect to the socket server using the following command:

```
io('http://ip:3001', { path: '/demo/socket' });
```

In your server side when creating the connection:

```
const io = require("socket.io");
    const socket = new io({
      path: "/demo/socket",
      serveClient: false /*whether to serve the client files (true/false)*/,
      orgins: "*" /*Supports cross orgine i.e) it helps to work in different browser*/,
      pingTimeout: 6000 /*how many ms the connection needs to be opened before we receive a ping from client i.e) If the client/ front end doesnt send a ping to the server for x amount of ms the connection will be closed in the server end for that specific client*/,
      pingInterval: 6000 /* how many ms before sending a new ping packet */
    });
socket.listen(http);
```

Note:
To avoid complication start you http server first and then start you sockets.
There are other options available, but the above are the most common ones.

I am just describing what i see in the socket.io document available in github.[socket_config](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/9c1e73c752aec63f48b511330a506d037783d897/docs/API.md#new-serverhttpserver-options). Hope this helps

Comment: Could you please explain in my code where I need to change this above code. I couldn't understand the path and server client arguments. Whether this need to update in server or client code.

Comment: I have added the code above. I hope the above info helps

Comment: whether I need to update this socket configuration code in my socket.io file. I have updated the socket.io full code above. Could you please check that and let me know where to use this configuration in my socket.io file.

Comment: I have updated the code. There are many ways to start a sockets. If you are configuring the socket, do not start it before you configure. In you code var io = require('socket.io')(http); this would immediately start the socket and listen to node http server. You have to configure your socket first and then start it. To avoid unnecessary conflicts i would only start sockets after the server is started.

Comment: Is there will get problem if connection get increase. Now in single socket there is more than 30000 concurrent usage will it be affect in this case?

Comment: I dont know for sure because i have not tested it, but from the documentation i have read it can support more than 30000 concurrent connections. This also depends upon how you structure your code, how many messages you are sending per minute/second and the processing power of the machine that you are running nodejs. In socket.io when a user logs in, a socket is created with an unique-id. Theoretically i can have as many unique-id your memory can support and you also have the ability to create custom socket unique-id's.